# Explanation of kirchoffs voltage law

Tags: electricity

Could somebody please explain why the voltage law is true? In particular why can an electron not simply move around the circuit and not give up all of their energy? And so why do electrons go through the circuit and no matter what arrangement they will have lost all of it by the time it gets back to the start?

Answer (score 1):

Electrons will only move through a circuit when they experience an electric field. Electric fields apply a force to electrically charged objects $F=qE$. Electric charges also generate electric fields $E=\frac{kq}{r^2}$. Inside a conductor, electric charges are free to move about, so they will naturally organize themselves so that they experience no net force from all the other charges. The end result is no electric field inside the conductor and all unbalanced charges on the surface. This happens nearly instantaneously.

When you apply an imbalance of charge across a conductor, like with a battery, this creates a non-zero electric field and attempts to balance the charges. Quickly, the conductor moves the imbalance of charge until it hits a resistive element. Any time charge moves from the conductor to the resistor, a corresponding amount of charge moves from the battery to the conductor. But this process can't happen nearly instantaneously across the resistor. The resistance to movement of charge creates a gradient in the electric charge within the conductor, resulting in a nonzero electric field.

Electric field is a vector, meaning it has a magnitude and direction for every point in space. There is a simpler quantity that makes dealing with electric systems easier, electric potential $V=Ed$. The electric field is a scalar quantity, so there is only the value of the electric potential at a point. Electric potential is measured in volts, which is why it is usually referred to as voltage.

One property of voltage is that its value at any point is only determined by the distribution of electric charges. This property means that the voltage difference between any two points is independent of which path you trace from point A to point B. Any path that loops around and comes back to its starting point must have a voltage difference of 0.

Electrical energy is stored in the electric field, not carried by electrons. When there is a current, the electrons don't gain or lose energy. They only gain or lose energy when the current changes. Resistive elements of a circuit dissipate energy because the electric field is non-zero within them.

Comment: Could you expand on the "resistive elements dissipate energy".

Comment: And so, is using the theory of electricity which is electrons moving and colliding incorrect for the electric field answer to this question? Because I have been using that for my reasoning.

Comment: The electric field is what makes electrons move, and resistors make movement of electrons cost more energy than just increasing the kinetic energy necessary. An electric current is just a mass movement of charge, but the individual charges move very slowly. So there is a bit of mixing of metaphors going on.

Comment: Why could an electron not be moved through the electric field and not dissipate all of its energy? If you catch my drift

Comment: Electrons don't move through the whole circuit. Only to the neighboring atom. In a conductor, that's costs virtually no energy. In a resistor, it costs more energy.